# draggable is not a function - how to add draggable as an extension to jQuery UI?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I am wondering how can I add the draggable [(found here)](https://jqueryui.com/download/) functionality as an extension method in my project. I have jquery and jQuery UI already in the project and I am not allowed to extend the original files, therefore I need to add it as an extension and initialize it.

I've done something similar already (see [here](https://pastebin.com/jsPkiNDJ)), so now I have one extension function in my extension file. But I can't figure our how to do add the draggable in my extension file.

Finally, I am initializing the extension methods like this :

```
 string init = "var init = function() { " +
            "initJUI();" +  
            "if (typeof addJqueryEasing == 'function' ) { addJqueryEasing(jQuery, window); } ;"
```

Any tips?

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to initialise like this -

```
var init = function() {
    initJUI();
    if (typeof addJqueryEasing == 'function') {
        addJqueryEasing(jQuery, window);
    }
};
init();
```

OR

```
(function() {
    initJUI();
    if (typeof addJqueryEasing == 'function') {
        addJqueryEasing(jQuery, window);
    }
}());
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I know how to initialize it. The problem is that I don't know how to add it in the extension file as an extension method.

Comment: Add the required files in the page. To initialize the draggable  `$( "#draggable" ).draggable();`